# Performing effective Joins on many tables in Hive

Tags: hadoop, join, optimization, hive, query-optimization

I am joining about 14 tables to create the base table in Hive 1.2. Every table has millions of records and these are parameters used when executing the query

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;  
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=200000;  
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=200000;  
hive.exec.max.created.files=250000;  
hive.enforce.bucketing=true;  
hive.auto.convert.join=false;  
mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8192;  
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8192;  
mapred.reduce.child.java.opts=-Xmx8096m;  
mapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx8096m;  
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

I am using ORC file format, and bucketing the table based on ID and partitioning the tables based on year,quarter and month. The table obviously performs heavy computations in terms of joining. Please let me know any other parameters or performing a different strategy that can be used to perform the joins more effectively

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the size of your files and file blocks within your source tables. Every join that is done is essentially done to each file block so increasing the size of the files/blocks means that less joins need to be conducted. On the flip side larger files/blocks means less parallelization so there is some testing that needs to be done to find the right balance. You can adjust your block size by conducting a small file merge with the setting below. These settings will also produce 1 block per file which is ideal for performance in most cases.

```
-- config settings to be added to the DML that loads your source tables
-- these will merge the files into 500MB files with only one block per file
-- as long as the block size is set higher than the file size then only one block will be produced
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize = 524288000;
set dfs.block.size = 1073741824;
```